# Как с помощью библиотеки tkinter сделать так чтобы кнопка меняла значение переменной?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

У меня есть такой пример. Он не работает и я не понимаю почему.

```
from tkinter import *

def function():
    root = Tk()
    but = Button(root,text="Test question", width=30, height=5,)
    but.pack()

    def why(event):
        a = 1
    but.bind("<Button-1>", why)
    root.mainloop()
    if a == 1:
        print("all works")
```

Comment: @Alban когда я поставил global перед а, то видает ошибку            global a = 1
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: не конкретно перед `а`, а на строку выше

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция не видит переменную `a`, так как она определена вне её локальной области видимости и не является глобальной. Чтобы код заработал перед `a = 1` нужно добавить `global a`, но есть одно но, `all works` будет напечатано только после того как вы закроете окно, предварительно нажав на кнопку. Чтобы увидеть вывод при нажатии кнопки, вам нужно определить поведение прямо в функции `why()`. вот небольшой пример:

```
In [55]: def function():
    ...:     values = {'a':0}
    ...:     root = Tk()
    ...:     but = Button(root,text="Test question", width=30, height=5,)
    ...:     but.pack()
    ...:     def why(event):
    ...:         values['a'] +=1
    ...:         if values['a'] % 2 == 0:
    ...:             print('Hello!!!')
    ...:         else:
    ...:             print('World!!!')
    ...:     but.bind("<Button-1>", why)
    ...:     root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from tkinter import *

def function():
     a = 0
     root = Tk()
     but = Button(root,text="Test question", width=30, height=5,)
     but.pack()

     def why(event):
         nonlocal a
         a += 1
         print('a:', a)

     but.bind("<Button-1>", why)
     root.mainloop()
```